# Constrict user to fill just one of several properties

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

We have a block type in our EpiServer project that can have either specify a video to use (an `EPiServer.Url`) or a youtube id (`string`). The thing is that it only makes sense to use either of those, not both. Is there a way of marking one field readonly if the other is filled?

Answer (score 1):

Not using vanilla editors, I'm afraid. But you could fairly easily create a custom editor (dojo widget) for that use case.

Here's an example of a custom editor to display a checkbox list for selecting blocks, instead of the standard editor for **ContentArea** properties:
https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2016/create-a-custom-editor-for-a-content-area-in-episerver/

However, the same principles apply for any content type.

To be clear: you don't need a custom *property type*, just a *custom editor*. The backing property type could still be **string**, which would contain either the URL or the YouTube ID.

If you want the property to be more developer-friendly, you could create a block type with "YouTube ID" and "URL" properties, and then define a content property of that block type.

You would then use your custom editor to set either the "YouTube ID" or "URL" property of that "VideoBlock" property.

We have created a similar editor before, where the editor would either select a video using a dropdown, or specify a custom video stream URL.